# How to obtain a list of directories within a directory, like list.files(), but instead "list.dirs()"

Tags: r, directory

I am able to use `list.files()` to obtain a list of files in a given directory, but if I want to get a list of directories, how would I do this?  Is it somehow right in front of me as an option within `list.files()`?

Also, I'm using Windows, so if the answer is to shell out to some Linux/unix command, that won't work for me.

.NET for example has a `Directory.GetFiles()` method, and a separate `Directory.GetDirectories()`
method, so I figured R would have an analogous pair.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Update: A `list.dirs` function was added to the base package in revision 54353, which was included in the R-2.13.0 release in April, 2011.

```
list.dirs(path = ".", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
```

So my function below was only useful for a few months. :)

---

I couldn't find a base R function to do this, but it would be pretty easy to write your own using:

```
dir()[file.info(dir())$isdir]
```

Update: here's a function (now corrected for Timothy Jones' comment):

```
list.dirs <- function(path=".", pattern=NULL, all.dirs=FALSE,
  full.names=FALSE, ignore.case=FALSE) {
  # use full.names=TRUE to pass to file.info
  all <- list.files(path, pattern, all.dirs,
           full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE, ignore.case)
  dirs <- all[file.info(all)$isdir]
  # determine whether to return full names or just dir names
  if(isTRUE(full.names))
    return(dirs)
  else
    return(basename(dirs))
}
```

Comment: Bad form to call dir() twice - things might change in between calls (yeah, p=0.0000001) but still... One day!

Comment: @Spacedman -- I agree, it was more a proof-of-concept one-liner.  See my update.

Comment: You will need to remove the recursive argument from that otherwise your function won't work. In such circumstances, `list.files` and `dir` don't list any directories it finds as separate "files", instead, R lists any files found *within* those directories. As all of these will be files and not directories, your function returns a vector of `NA`

Comment: I did in fact get a vector of NA just now...I'm going to try this other approach

Comment: This doesn't work for me (I get a list of NA's too). Any ideas?

Comment: Oh- I figured it out. It's because the file.info() fails if `full.names=FALSE` and `path` isn't set to `'.'`. If you fix this, I'll give you the bounty :)

Comment: @TimothyJones: fixed. Thanks for the hint on what was broken.

Comment: This answer is now out of date. See Tal Galili's answer.

Answer (score 32):

`base` R now includes a [`list.dirs` function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/list.files.html), so home-brewed variants are no longer necessary.

For example:

```
list.dirs('.', recursive=FALSE)
```

Comment: +1 for `recursive = FALSE`, as otherwise it lists the current directory (.) and directories within a subdirectory.

Answer (score 19):

Just to update this thread:

I see that in the newer version of R (currently I'm using 2.5.1), there is now a `list.dirs` function included in the base install:

> list.dirs implicitly has all.files = TRUE, and if recursive = TRUE,
>   the answer includes path itself (provided it is a readable directory).

Comment: Have you used the built-in function? I can't get `all.files=TRUE` to work, it just doesn't show the whole path.

Comment: Yep, accepted answer is now out of date. `list.dirs()` is the best way to get this now.

Answer (score 8):

```
list.dirs <- function(...) {
    x <- dir(...)
    x[file_test("-d", x)]
}
```

might be of use?

How might we do this recursively? (the `recursive` argument of `dir` breaks these functions because it never returns directory names, just the files within each directory, etc...).

Comment: this doesn't work either, but thanks for answering.  I'll just play around with file.info and $dir until I get something that works

Comment: @user297400 You should not have accepted my answer as correct if it didn't work for you.

Answer (score 3):

What about something like this, give it a try:

```
dir('.')[file.info(dir('.',full.names=T))$isdir]
```

Answer (score 2):

You mention that you don't want to shell out to a Linux/UNIX command but I assume its ok to shell out to a Windows command.  In that case this would do it:

```
shell("dir/ad/b", intern = TRUE)
```

and this would do it recursively:

```
shell("dir/ad/b/s", intern = TRUE)
```

Normally I would prefer the platform independent solutions of others here but particularly for interactive use where you are just concerned with getting the answer as simply and directly as possible this may be less work.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem a while back and used this recursive code to find all directories. Perhaps this can be of use?

```
list.dirs <- function(parent=".")   # recursively find directories
{
    if (length(parent)>1)           # work on first and then rest
        return(c(list.dirs(parent[1]), list.dirs(parent[-1])))
    else {                          # length(parent) == 1
        if (!is.dir(parent))
            return(NULL)            # not a directory, don't return anything
        child <- list.files(parent, full=TRUE)
        if (!any(is.dir(child)))
            return(parent)          # no directories below, return parent
        else 
            return(list.dirs(child))    # recurse
    }
}

is.dir <- function(x)    # helper function
{
    ret <- file.info(x)$isdir
    ret[is.na(ret)] <- FALSE
    ret
}
```