# How does one use `Recall()` to write a recursive function to recursively list directories in a given directory?

Tags: r, recursion

This [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749783/how-to-obtain-a-list-of-directories-within-a-directory-like-list-files-but-in) asked about listing directories (not files) in the current directory. I noted in a comment to one of the answers that we can't use the `recursive` argument of functions like `dir` and `list.files` to recursively list directories in the current directory.

The obvious solution to this is to write a recursive function that lists the directories in the current directory that calls itself on each of those directories in turn, and so on, adding to the overall list of directories that gets returned at the end of the recursion.

The `Recall()` function would seem the ideal candidate for this, but I've never really got my head round how one writes a recursive function that adds to the final output each time it is called.

How would one modify this function:

```
list.dirs <- function(path) {
    x <- dir(path, full.names = TRUE)
    dnames <- x[file_test("-d", x)]
    dnames
}
```

To have it descend recursively through the directories in `dnames` adding any directories it finds to a list of all directories found within the `dnames` directories, and so on...?

Comment: I think my main problem is not really grepping how one is supposed to write a function to use `Recall` on itself?

Comment: To use `Recall` in a recursive function, call `Recall` instead of the name of the function.

Comment: @hadley Thanks, but I got that far via `?Recall`. It's how to arrange the returned objects and combine them that I am not quite getting my head round.

Comment: So maybe your confusion is not with the use of recall (which is pretty simple), but how to write a recursive function in general (which is really complicated) ?

Comment: @hadley yep I think you hit the nail on the head. I was hoping that if someone could show how to make the `list.dirs` function recursive using `Recall` I'd have a better idea of how it worked. I was flailing about for quite a while trying to to come up with a recursive version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
list.dirs <- function(path) {
     x <- dir(path, full.names = TRUE)
     dnames <- x[file_test("-d", x)]
    tmp <- character(0)
    for(i in seq_along(dnames) ) {
        tmp <- c(tmp, Recall(dnames[i]) )
    }
     c(dnames,tmp)
 }
```

This just tacks the subdirectories onto the end, some different logic could be used to give a different ordering.

Comment: Thanks Greg. That is effectively what I came up with on my commute home. I was sure I'd tried this before posting but if I did I was doing something wrong as it failed then.

Comment: One thing that's not super clear in this example is what the terminal case is - for recursive functions it's usually a good idea to clearly label the base case.  In this function it happens naturally when `length(dnamaes) == 0`, but I think it would be clear with an explicit return.

Comment: @hadley Excellent point, and I think this is where I was going wrong initially. Trying to follow the Fibonacci sequence function in the examples of `?Recall` I saw that had such a terminal case and tried to insert that into my attempt. I was obviously doing it wrong though, as when I did insert something that was all it returned!  Where would one insert the terminal case check and what form would it take? Would it be `if(length(dnames) == 0) return(tmp)` inserted before the loop starts?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Without that, you'd also have problems if you didn't know about `seq_along` and did `1:length(dnames)`